# try to print on BIXOLON SRP-350plusII, but it can't get my design right

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, reportviewer

i have a task to do on "POS" system, instead the old system witch was VB 6.0 and Access, i try to make a new one with SQL Server, ADO.NET and C#, so i try to print bills out of BIXOLON printer, but when i design my report it doesn't appear correct, it looks like this:
[image]
here is some shots of my test project (this isn't my real project, its just testing)
[image]
[image]
[image]
Some code:

```
 private void ID()
    {
        cn.Open();
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Max(ID)+1 FROM Info", cn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            int i = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            textBox1.Text = i.ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
            textBox1.Text = "1";
        }
        cn.Close();
    }
    private void LoadGrid()
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

        SqlDataAdapter ADAP = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Info", cn);
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        ADAP.Fill(DS, "Info");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables["Info"];
        textBox2.SelectAll();
        textBox2.Focus();
    }
    private void Insert()
    {
        if (textBox2.Text != "")
        {
            SqlCommand cmd;
            cn.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Info (Name, Date) VALUES (@Name, @Date)", cn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox2.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now.ToString());
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Empty!");
            textBox2.Focus();
        }
    }
    private void Delete()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE Info WHERE ID = @ID", cn);
        cn.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", textBox1.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'infoDataSet1.Info' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.InfoTableAdapter.Fill(this.infoDataSet1.Info);
        LoadGrid();
        ID();
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadGrid();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Insert();
        LoadGrid();
        ID();
        textBox2.Focus();
        textBox2.Text = "";
    }

    private void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            Insert();
            LoadGrid();
            ID();
            textBox2.Focus();
            textBox2.Text = "";
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Delete();
        LoadGrid();
        ID();
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
            textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'infoDataSet1.Info' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.InfoTableAdapter.Fill(this.infoDataSet1.Info);
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
}
```

now i need help to make it out like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set Margin to 0 all around(left, right, top, bottom)